# regex to replace two separate things separately in one replace

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I need to replace `1` with a `0`, and replace `0` with `1` in a string. I know how to replace one thing with another, but how can I replace two separately. See the attempt below.

```
const broken = str => {
  return str.replace(/1/g, '0').replace(/0/g, '1');
}
```

This is an example:

input

> 011101

output

> 100010

Comment: `I know I could do it in 2 stages` Wouldn't work like that, then all `0`s and `1`s would be turned into `1`s

Comment: @CertainPerformance you are dead right, I probably shouldn't have said that and only realised when I tried it :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a function and an object for taking the replacement value.

```js
const broken = str => str.replace(/[01]/g, match => ({ 0: 1, 1: 0 }[match]));

console.log(broken('1100'));
```

Comment: what does the `m` mean?

Comment: it is the matched value.

Comment: This is exactly the same principle as in the duplicate question.

Comment: Another option which will work only in this particular situation would be to subtract from 1: `match => 1 - match` :)