# check for number of occurrences of 2 strings in string js

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I am looking for the number of occurences of two different patterns in a string. I am looking for `fly` or `flies`. I am able to find the occurrence of one, but not sure how to check for 2 different strings.

My attempt so far is

```
const flyCount = str => {
   return (str.match(/fly/g) || str.match(/flies/g) || []).length;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Combine the regex expressions to find both words.

Note: use [`\b`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backspace) (word boundary) to find exact words. If the words can be a part of other words, remove the `\b`.

```js
const flyCount = str =>
   (str.match(/\b(?:fly|flies)\b/g) || []).length;

const result = flyCount('Look how he flies. He can fly');

console.log(result);
```

2. Or get the length of each expression and sum them:

```js
const flyCount = str =>
   (str.match(/\bfly\b/g) || []).length + (str.match(/\bflies\b/g) || []).length;

const result = flyCount('Look how he flies. He can fly');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks! will mark as answer. was thinking that, but wasn't sure if there was a another way based on something I had seen yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52909815/regex-to-replace-two-separate-things-separately-in-one-replace/52909853?noredirect=1#comment92730394_52909853

Comment: Wouldn't `return str.match(/fly|flies/g).length;` be easier?

Comment: @Andy - thanks. I was working on both answers with an annoying child in the background :)

Comment: @peterflanagan, would you count "butterfly/butterflies" etc in your occurance list? Or is it just the actual words "fly" and "flies"?

Comment: @andyI would count them too

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the `|` regex operator. You may also want to consider adding the `\b` word boundary.

```js
const flyCount = str => (str.match(/\b(?:fly|flies)\b/g) || []).length

console.log(flyCount('One fly, two flies'))
```